# Is HikariCP autocommit usage the same as regular java connection autocommit usage?

Tags: java, connection, rollback, hikaricp, autocommit

I recently uses HikariCP. Before I use my own simple ConnectionPool to meet our needs. In our software sometimes we need to perform multiple database inserts where each inserts depends on some validation. More or less like the sample from this site: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html#commit_transactions

In my old way, when I was using my own conn pool, I will always set the connection object to setAutoCommit(false) before giving it to the requesting object so the database manager can rollback the data manually when something goes wrong. Like in the sample, if the try catches any exceptions, then it will call the rollback function. When I return the connection, I call the connection.commit() in the connection return and set autocommit back to true in the connection pool manager.

My question: does HikariCP still uses the same procedure for my needs? Meaning, set the autocommit to false (I read the manual, you have autocommit parameters for your config), and then we just manually rollback or commit the transaction then return to the pool? Or is there some automation done where we can just throw an exception and HikariCP will automatically call the rollback upon error or call commit upon connection return if I do not set the config param for Autocommit = false?

Thank you for any info.
Rendra

Answer (score 6):

HikariCP auto-commit behavior is the same as without a pool.  If autoCommit=false, you are responsible for commit/rollback in a try-finally.  So, yes, you just commit/rollback and then return the connection to the pool.

The truth is that if autoCommit=false, and you run queries without committing, then HikariCP will automatically rollback on return to the pool.  However, this is for safety and I discourage you from coding based on this behavior.  Doing so will make your code less portable if you ever choose to switch pools.

Comment: Hi Brett. Sorry for the long time no reply. I am intrigued by your statement that you discourage setting autocommit=false. In my case where I have chains of tables that needs to be updated completely before a transaction is considered successful, wouldn't autocommit cause partial update? For example, In my web service, it would update table 1, then table 2, then table 3. If any of the table (say table 2 or 3) update fail, then I would want to roll back all transactions within the tables from the same process/service.

Comment: I'm not saying don't use autoCommit=false.  I simply mean to be sure to commit your transactions, or HikariCP will roll them back.